# Using reusable components in Vue 2 in comination with vue router

Tags: components, vue.js, vue-router

I seem to do something wrong when I'm trying to target child components in nested router-views with click events.

**Current situation:**
I have a component one and component two. Both have a child component called dialog.

Component one and two are being loaded through a router-view in parent component dashboard. Each view has a button to show their child component "Modal".

The button seems to work fine on the view that gets loaded on pageload. But as soon as I switch routes the showModal function does not know the dialog element from which view to target.

I thought the components would be destroyed and rebuilt upon switching routes but apparently not.

Here is my code, I hope someone is able to help:

**App**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * include Vue and Vue Resource. This gives a great starting point for
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap')

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the body of the page. From here, you may begin adding components to
 * the application, or feel free to tweak this setup for your needs.
 */

Vue.component('vuetest', require('./components/vuetest.vue'))

const Dashboard = require('./components/dashboard.vue')
const FirstRoute = require('./components/firstroute.vue')
const Second = require('./components/secondroute.vue')

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/dashboard',
        component: Dashboard,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'firstview',
                name: 'firstview',
                canReuse: false,
                component: FirstRoute
            },
            {
                path: 'secondview',
                name: 'secondview',
                canReuse: false,
                component: Second
            }
        ]
    }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes // short for routes: routes
})

window.EventHub = new Vue()

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});
```

**Vuetest**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Vue Test</h1>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        created() {

        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component ready.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Dashboard Route**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        <navigation></navigation>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    Vue.component('navigation', require('./navigation.vue'))
</script>
```

**Navigation**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'firstview' }">first</router-link>
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'secondview' }">second</router-link>
    </div>
</template>
```

**First Route**

```
<template>
    <div class="firstroute">
        <h1>First Route</h1>
        <button class="showmodal" v-on:click="showModal">Showmodal</button>
        <modal></modal>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            showModal: function () {
                EventHub.$emit('showModal')
            }
        }
    }
    Vue.component('modal', require('./modal.vue'));
</script>
```

**Second Route**

```
<template>
    <div class="secondroute">
        <h1>Second Route</h1>
        <button class="showmodal" v-on:click="showModal">Showmodal</button>
        <modal></modal>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            showModal: function () {
                EventHub.$emit('showModal')
            }
        }
    }
    Vue.component('modal', require('./modal.vue'));
</script>
```

**Modal**

```
<template>
    <div class="dialog hidden">
        Dialog
    </div>
</template>
<style>
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<script>
    export default{
        created() {
            EventHub.$on('showModal', this.showModal);
        },
        methods: {
            showModal: function() {
                document.querySelector('.dialog').classList.toggle('hidden');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

tiny recomendations

':class' directive instead of native code:

```
document.querySelector('.dialog').classList.toggle('hidden');
```

components:

```
import Modal from './modal' 

export default {
  ...
  components:
    Modal
  }
  ...
}
```

instead of

```
Vue.component('modal', require('./modal.vue'));
```

.. also Vuex is a good point for this case

additional:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools

https://jsfiddle.net/uLaj738k/2/

Comment: Thanks for your answer Aleksandr. Your help is much appreciated. I've refactored as per your recommendations. 

Can I ask a bit more info on why you feel Vuex would be the answer here? Currently it doesn't feel that state management is the right this to use to keep track of which route an action should take place in. 

I'm not trying to move any data between routes, I'm 'just' trying to get a button to show/hide an element in the currently active route.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the problem was the moment I called the querySelector method.

Assigning the `.dialog` element to a const in `mounted()` solved my problem.